# Using redux toolkit with server actions next js 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit, next.js13

So i been reading about server actions in next js 14 since next is generally built around it and i'm a huge fan of redux toolkit. so was wondering if it's possible to use useAppDispatch() etc with server actions in next js since  to the best of my knowledge and from the research i've don so far it's only possible with client components. for example let's take the code below in a server component

```
"use server";
import { createProduct } from "@/app/schema/model.schema";
import { useAppDispatch } from "@/app/store/hooks";

import { createProductModel } from "@/app/store/slices/model/modelService";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export const adminCreateProduct = async (data: createProduct) => {
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
try {

 const products = await dispatch(createProductModel(data));

  revalidatePath("/");

  return products;
} catch (error) {
 console.log(error);
 throw new Error("Interal Error");
 }
};
```

Now if we try to call the code in a client component it fails. So was wondering if there's a way to go about this . Thanks